# Probability of choosing same color

Tags: probability

Gita and Sita choose one color each out of 3 Colors red blue and orange. What is the probability that both of them choose orange?

Comment: Do they choose the colours at random with equal probability? And do they choose independently?

Comment: Your title and your question are different problems.  The probability of choosing the same color is different than the probability of them both choosing orange.

Comment: This homework question can be answered exactly how it is asked. The probability is 1/9 as sample space set has 9 occurrences for 3 colors and 2 picks.

Comment: Umair: Does the problem state that the probability of Gita picking each color is $1/3$? Or did you just *assume* that? Consider the (roughly) parallel problem: by the end of the day, I'll either be alive or dead. So will you. Does that mean the probability that we both die is $1/4$?

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere between 0 and 1. For instance, we can add to the information given the following (which does not contradict anything said in the problem statement):

1. "Gita always chooses Orange; Sita always chooses Blue."

In this case, the probability that they both pick orange is zero.

Alternatively, we could add the following:

2. "Gita always chooses Orange; so does Sita."

In this case, the desired probability is 1.

Because both additions are consistent with the problem statement, both are valid solutions. And indeed, if we say

3. "Gita always chooses Orange. Sita chooses Orange with probability $s$ and Blue with probability $1-s$",

which is also consistent, for any number $0 \le s \le 1$, then the probability that they pick the same color is $s$, showing that all values between 0 and 1 are valid answers.

Your book or professor doubtless intended that you give Brahadeesh's answer, but should have phrased the problem more carefully. (Or perhaps the book/prof *did* phrase the problem more carefully, and your transcription of it was lacking -- I don't mean to ascribe fault where none belongs.)